# Finding element within a specific range

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dom structure like this

```
 <p>
    <script type="highlight/begin"></script>
        <span>Some text </span>
</p>
<p> Some text</p>
<p>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <script type="highlight/end"></script>
<p>
```

Is  there any way in jquery by which I can access all the elements in between `<script type="highlight/begin` and `<script type="highlight/end">`?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, although you should note that this is completely invalid HTML, so the output would not look as you seem to be expecting it to.

Comment: Strongly recommend not doing it that way, not least because it abuses `script` tags to use them for things that aren't scripts. It's also invalid (at least as shown). You might use comments, that's a fairly common way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My bad I have updated the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend like the comments say, to not do it like this way because its unconventional.

This is the way I would use JQuery to find and element in a specific range:

```
<div class="highlight">
  <p>text here</p>
  [FIND THIS TEXT]
  <p>More text</p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){

    var p = $(".highlight p")[0];
    var textNode = p.nextSibling;
    var text = textNode.textContent;

    console.log(text);
});
```